# Can you help me with multiple errors in C?

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to C and I'm having difficulty with a few different concepts, including pointers, arrays, and reading files. Here is my program I've started, I'm sure their are a few errors, could you show me what I'm doing wrong? The program is supposed to read the letters from congress.txt and store them as capital letters without spaces, I also tried to make a little test which will print the letters for me so I can see if the characters in the array store are correct. I've heard that I shouldn't test against != EOF here before but my teacher has used that and I don't want to simply copy something I don't understand.

This is what is in congress.txt:

Congress shall make no law respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or abridging the freedom of speech, or of the press; or the right of the people peaceably to assemble, and to petition the government for a redress of grievances.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int processFile(int *store);
int cipher(int *store, int *code);

int main(void){
    int store[300], code[300], i;

    processFile(store);
    for (i = 0; store[i] != 0; ++i){    //does a print test of store so I can see      if the txt was stored properly
        printf("%c", store[i]);
    }
    getchar();
    return;
}

int processFile(int *store){
    int i, a = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen("congress.txt", "r");

    for (i = 0; a != EOF;){
        fscanf(f, "%c", &a);        //store character in a
        if (a <= 'Z' && a >= 'A'){  //store capital letters
            store[i] = a;
            i++;
        }
        if (a <= 'z' && a >= 'a'){  //store lower case letters as capital
            store[i] = a - 32;
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read more about the "EOF anti-pattern" here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941 and http://drpaulcarter.com/cs/common-c-errors.php#4.2  Your use is slightly different than usual, but the key point is that `fscanf()` can return `EOF`, and when it does, `a`'s value is unchanged  (`fscanf()` actually will do nothing to `a` when it hits `EOF` - it won't write `EOF` into `a`).

Comment: `fscanf` will never set `a` to `EOF`. And `fscanf` is overkill for reading a single character. Just use `getchar()`, and assign the result to an `int`, not a `char`, so you can detect `EOF`. Don't use magic numbers; see `isupper` and `islower` in `<ctype.h>` (and be sure to cast the argument to `unsigned char`).

Comment: ok so basically the loop never ends then?

Comment: how can I make getchar() read values from my file?

Comment: short version: `EOF` is not a character, it's a special value used to signal that a read operation failed (depending on the actual read function used, sometimes it means actually that end of file occurred; sometimes it means that any error occurred).  Check the documentation for whichever read function you are calling (`fscanf` in this case) to see what it does in case of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop doesn't make any sense.

```
for (i = 0; b != NULL; i++)
    printf("%s", store[i]);
    b = store[i + 1];
}
```

`store[i]` is an `int`, so you can't print it with `"%s"`. I think you meant `printf("%c", store[i]);` which means to print the characters whose character code is that int (which is OK, because you read this earlier with `scanf`).

`b != NULL` should be `b != 0`, but this tests an uninitialized value of `b` on the first time around the loop. Try this instead:

```
for ( i = 0; store[i] != 0; ++i )
    printf("%c", store[i]);
```

In the other piece of code, `65`, `90`, `97`, `122` are more clearly expressed as `'A'`, `'Z'`, `'a'`, `'z'` respectively.

You may want to consider using the `isupper`, `islower` functions from `<ctype.h>`.  `a - 32` should be replaced by `toupper(a);`.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
fscanf(f, "%c", a);
```

should be:

```
fscanf(f, "%c", &a);
```

Comment: ah Thanks, I was wondering why their was an error on that line!

Answer (score 1):

I would change your body of processFile to:

```
int i, a = 0;
FILE *f = fopen("congress.txt", "r");

if(f) 
{
    for( i=0; i<300 && ((a=fgetc(f)) != EOF); i++)
    {
        if ( isupper(a) ){  //store capital letters
            store[i] = a;
        }
        else if ( islower(a) ){  //store lower case letters as capital
            store[i] = toupper(a);
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
}
if (i==300) i--;
store[i] = 0; // always put a zero after the last element 
              // since your loop in main depends on it to exit.
```

This takes care of EOF problems, and also fixes potential overflows of the `store` array.  (You might want to pass store's max size to the routine instead of hardcoding 300...)